# What is the correct way to develop a Sublime Text 3 plugin?

Tags: sublimetext3

I have a very simple question regarding sublime text plugin development. I developed a plugin and put it into a currently private BitBucket repository. In order to have others test it I can zip it into a myplugin.sublime-plugin file and distribute - so far so good. To develop however I have it stored under `.../Sublime Text 3/Packages` and everything works just fine **except that when I close Sublime Text 3 and restart it will delete the plugin folder**. Currently I clone again but as that is a bit annoying I was wondering if that is not the correct way to do things and if so what would the correct way be?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good solution but after a lot of research the only way to avoid the automatic uninstall on restart that I found is to delete the `package-metadata.json` from the plugin.

This avoids a check for the repository (which cannot be accessed) and the plugin is not uninstalled.